# Drupal white screen after installation

Tags: drupal

i am getting the white screen after installin drupal. My memory limit is 128M  in php.ini and the settings.php points to the database. What needs to be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called White Screen of Death. To check what is going on you have to do the following ..

Enable error reporting, temporarily edit your index.php file (normally located in your root directory) directly after the first opening PHP tag (do not edit the actual file info!) to add the following:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);  
// $Id: index.php,v 1.94 2007/12/26...
```

This was taken from this url http://drupal.org/node/158043

Answer (score 0):

You can check the log files in c:/wamp/logs in windows

Answer (score 0):

Even after adding that to my index.php file the screen is still white.

Found the error in a local log file on my MAC in /Applications/MAMP/logs